# elif not working as expected and the loop starts again

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

inside a while loop all the if and elif statements are working except `elif user_choice.upper() == "C"`

I tried inputting the choice C and expected the program to print "miles travelled" but the program went and again asked for input

```
# Game info
print("Welcome to camel")
print("You have stolen a camel too make your way across the great Mobi desert")
print("The natives are chasing you and want their camel back. Survive and run out the natives")

# Storing values in variables
miles_travelled = 0
drinks_canteen = 3
natives_travelled = -20
camel_tiredness = 0
players_thirst = 0
done = False

# Making the loop
while not done:
    print("A. Drink from your canteen")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed")
    print("C. Ahead full speed")
    print("D. Stop for the night")
    print("E. Status check")
    print("F. Quit")
    user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
    if user_choice.upper() == "A":
        if drinks_canteen == 0:
            print("No drinks in your canteen")
            user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
        elif drinks_canteen != 0:
            drinks_canteen -= 1
    elif user_choice.upper() == "B":
        miles_travelled += 7
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 1
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper == "C":
        miles_travelled += 15
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 3
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "D":
        camel_tiredness = 0
        print("The camel is happy")
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "E":
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        print("Drinks in canteen:", drinks_canteen)
        print("The natives are", natives_travelled, "behind you")
    elif user_choice.upper() == "F":
        print("Game Ends")
        done = True
    elif 4 < players_thirst < 6:
        print("You are thirsty")
    elif players_thirst > 6:
        print("You died of thirst")
        done = True
    elif 5 < camel_tiredness < 8:
        print("Your camel is getting tired")
    elif camel_tiredness > 8:
        print("Your camel died")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled:
        print("The natives caught up")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled > 200:
        print("You won")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled + 15:
        print("The natives are getting close")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of linking to code on GitHub

Comment: Don't expect anyone to answer your question if you can't paste the code into the question. It will help if you can pare the code down to a minimum that shows the problem.

Comment: Typo: `elif user_choice.upper == "C":` You forgot the `()`.

Comment: You can avoid this kind of mistake by just doing the `upper()` call once, when you input the text: `user_choice = input("Your choice? ").upper()`. Then you can remove it from all your conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a pair of brackets. Replace `elif user_choice.upper == "C":` with `elif user_choice.upper() == "C":`. Complete code below:

```
# Game info
print("Welcome to camel")
print("You have stolen a camel too make your way across the great Mobi desert")
print("The natives are chasing you and want their camel back. Survive and run out the natives")

# Storing values in variables
miles_travelled = 0
drinks_canteen = 3
natives_travelled = -20
camel_tiredness = 0
players_thirst = 0
done = False

# Making the loop
while not done:
    print("A. Drink from your canteen")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed")
    print("C. Ahead full speed")
    print("D. Stop for the night")
    print("E. Status check")
    print("F. Quit")
    user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
    if user_choice.upper() == "A":
        if drinks_canteen == 0:
            print("No drinks in your canteen")
            user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
        elif drinks_canteen != 0:
            drinks_canteen -= 1
    elif user_choice.upper() == "B":
        miles_travelled += 7
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 1
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper == "C":
        miles_travelled += 15
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 3
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "D":
        camel_tiredness = 0
        print("The camel is happy")
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "E":
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        print("Drinks in canteen:", drinks_canteen)
        print("The natives are", natives_travelled, "behind you")
    elif user_choice.upper() == "F":
        print("Game Ends")
        done = True
    elif 4 < players_thirst < 6:
        print("You are thirsty")
    elif players_thirst > 6:
        print("You died of thirst")
        done = True
    elif 5 < camel_tiredness < 8:
        print("Your camel is getting tired")
    elif camel_tiredness > 8:
        print("Your camel died")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled:
        print("The natives caught up")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled > 200:
        print("You won")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled + 15:
        print("The natives are getting close")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a pair of parentheses at the user_choice.upper = "C". Also, you need to split your if statements into two sections: one for getting input and one for calculating the effect. Finally, you need to remove the user input after print("No drinks in your canteen"). Here is the updated code:

```
# Game info
print("Welcome to camel")
print("You have stolen a camel too make your way across the great Mobi desert")
print("The natives are chasing you and want their camel back. Survive and run out the natives")

# Storing values in variables
miles_travelled = 0
drinks_canteen = 3
natives_travelled = -20
camel_tiredness = 0
players_thirst = 0
done = False

# Making the loop
while not done:
    print("A. Drink from your canteen")
    print("B. Ahead moderate speed")
    print("C. Ahead full speed")
    print("D. Stop for the night")
    print("E. Status check")
    print("F. Quit")
    user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
    if user_choice.upper() == "A":
        if drinks_canteen == 0:
            print("No drinks in your canteen")
            #user_choice = input("Your choice? ")
        elif drinks_canteen != 0:
            drinks_canteen -= 1
    elif user_choice.upper() == "B":
        miles_travelled += 7
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 1
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "C":
        miles_travelled += 15
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        players_thirst += 1
        camel_tiredness += 3
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "D":
        camel_tiredness = 0
        print("The camel is happy")
        natives_travelled += 9
    elif user_choice.upper() == "E":
        print("Miles travelled:", miles_travelled)
        print("Drinks in canteen:", drinks_canteen)
        print("The natives are", natives_travelled, "behind you")
    elif user_choice.upper() == "F":
        print("Game Ends")
        done = True

    if 4 < players_thirst < 6:
        print("You are thirsty")
    elif players_thirst > 6:
        print("You died of thirst")
        done = True
    elif 5 < camel_tiredness < 8:
        print("Your camel is getting tired")
    elif camel_tiredness > 8:
        print("Your camel died")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled:
        print("The natives caught up")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled > 200:
        print("You won")
        done = True
    elif miles_travelled == natives_travelled + 15:
        print("The natives are getting close")
```